# Elasticsearch Installation Conflicts

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to install Elasticsearch on my local machine. I have download the Elasticsearch and try to setup it as following [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch)
But when I'm trying to `Run bin/elasticsearch` it shows permission error for logs. Then I tried to run it as `sudo bin/elasticsearch`  then it shows following error

```
[2017-11-20T12:08:40,340][WARN ][o.e.b.ElasticsearchUncaughtExceptionHandler] [] uncaught exception in thread [main]
org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.StartupException: java.lang.RuntimeException: can not run elasticsearch as root
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:134) ~[elasticsearch-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:121) ~[elasticsearch-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:69) ~[elasticsearch-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:134) ~[elasticsearch-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90) ~[elasticsearch-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:92) ~[elasticsearch-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:85) ~[elasticsearch-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: can not run elasticsearch as root
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.initializeNatives(Bootstrap.java:104) ~[elasticsearch-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:171) ~[elasticsearch-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:322) ~[elasticsearch-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:130) ~[elasticsearch-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    ... 6 more
```

Need instructions to fix this thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should give the `logs` dir the permissions(drwxrwxr-x) of your current user, and start es by `bin/elasticsearch`(Don't start as root!).

Answer (score 0):

I found following documentation [ElasticSearch Hello World Example](http://www.mkyong.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-hello-world-example/) . As I using Linux OS I followed the **1.4 Ubuntu Linux: Install with commands**